# Multiple .tf files in a folder

Tags: terraform

I have a project that I inherited that has multiple .tf `(main.tf, xyz.tf, ...)` files in certain folders. When it does a `source = "../<folder_name>"`, what order are the files applied in ? I main.tf always applied first followed by the rest ?

Note: These are different from the `variables.tf and outputs.tf` files.

Answer (score 15):

In Terraform 0.11, regular `*.tf` files were [loaded in alphabetical order](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration-0-11/load.html) and then override files were applied.

> When invoking any command that loads the Terraform configuration, Terraform loads all configuration files within the directory specified in alphabetical order.
>
> ...
>
> Override files are the exception, as they're loaded after all non-override files, in alphabetical order.

In Terraform 0.12+ (including 1.x), the load order of `*.tf` files is [no longer specified](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/files#directories-and-modules). Behind the scenes Terraform reads all of the files in a directory and then determines a resource ordering that makes sense regardless of the order the files were actually read.

> Terraform evaluates all of the configuration files in a module, effectively treating the entire module as a single document. Separating various blocks into different files is purely for the convenience of readers and maintainers, and has no effect on the module's behavior.

Comment: Docs have moved https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/files