# can we order .tf files in terraform?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

Asking a novice question as I am new to terraform.

I have 4 *.tf files in a folder (no main.tf file).

```
a.tf
b.tf
c.tf
d.tf
```

I want to define the order of execution as below-

```
c.tf
d.tf
a.tf
b.tf
```

I referred to [Multiple .tf files in a folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59515702/multiple-tf-files-in-a-folder). As per it, the ordering is alphabetical.

how shall I achieve it?

Comment: In most cases, if the sequence of the terraform files matters, and you encounter this problem, you probably don't have the correct folder structure or doing something else wrong. Can you please explain why it are 4 files, that are dependent but can't be in one file? Or what else the reason is why the sequence is important? So that we can help you with a great solution that also follows best practices. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no order of execution in TF.

Comment: Terraform will read all the files in the location and will then form a dependency graph which will decide in which order to apply the resources.  You can see this running `terraform graph`. In most cases it will use implicit dependency. If you have a resource that needs another resource but not implicitly, you can explicitly list that depency by using the meta attribute `depends_on`. That will force terraform order of these resources.

Answer (score 2):

Terraform does not make any use of the order of `.tf` files or of the declarations in those files. Instead, Terraform decodes all of the blocks across all of your files and analyzes them to look for references between objects.

For example, you might have a `variables.tf` file containing the following:

```
variable "example" {
  type = string
}
```

...and you might have a `compute.tf` file containing the following:

```
resource "example" "example" {
  name = var.example
}
```

Terraform can see that `resource "example" "example"` contains a reference to `var.example`, which corresponds with the `variable "example"` block.

Therefore Terraform knows that it should deal with `variable "example"` before it should deal with `resource "example" "example"`, even though they are in two different files. You could instead place them both in the same file in either order and the meaning would be identical.

When thinking about order of operations in Terraform, the primary concern is making sure that all of the objects have the right references between one another. In many cases the correct ordering emerges naturally from the data flow you'd be describing anyway, but if not then you can add additional references or you can use [`depends_on`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/meta-arguments/depends_on) to describe additional dependencies that Terraform would not otherwise be able to see.

Answer (score 2):

You can order `.tf` (and/or `.tf.json`) files as you like but this will not change how Terraform is going to handle dependencies in your infrastructure configuration.

***In fact, managing dependencies is one of the strengths of Terraform!*** Very useful not only when creating but also when updating and deleting resources.

Also the naming of `.tf` files is irrelevant as well as the ordering of resources within the files (see below). Basically, Terraform first reads all data present in all `.tf` files and then creates a dependency graph based on ***implicit dependencies*** (whenever a resource [references another resource or data source by name](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/references)). Note: Terraform reads only the `.tf` files that are present in the current folder and not in subfolders!

It is possible to configure ***explicit dependencies*** by using the [`depends_on` meta-argument](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/meta-arguments/depends_on)–but this should be only used as a last resort as it has the potential to slow down infrastructure provisioning.

Here you can learn more about dependencies: [Create resource dependencies](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/tutorials/configuration-language/dependencies).

#### Visualize the dependency graph

you can visualize all dependencies using for instance:

```
terraform graph | dot -Tpng > graph.png
```

Get help on the `terraform graph` command:

```
% terraform graph -help
Usage: terraform [global options] graph [options]

  Produces a representation of the dependency graph between different
  objects in the current configuration and state.

  The graph is presented in the DOT language. The typical program that can
  read this format is GraphViz, but many web services are also available
  to read this format.
```

#### Some `tf` file naming conventions

Quote from [Terraform docs: Files](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/files)

> *A Terraform module only consists of the top-level configuration files in a directory; nested directories are treated as completely separate modules, and are not automatically included in the configuration.
> Terraform evaluates all of the configuration files in a module, effectively treating the entire module as a single document. Separating various blocks into different files is purely for the convenience of readers and maintainers, and has no effect on the module's behavior.*

The most common Terraform file naming convention concerns variables. They are defined in a separate file typically named `variables.tf`. Variables’s values can be assigned in variable definitions files. For the variable definitions file one should stick to the naming `terraform.tfvars` or `terraform.tfvars.json` unless one wants to provide another name as a command-line option.

#### Using modules to organize infrastructure configuration

A complex infrastructure may be split into several *modules*. Modules can be in subfolders but they need to be called from the main module. For instance, you can create two modules `web` and `database` in subfolders of the main folder:

```
my-terraform-project/
├── main.tf
└── modules/
    ├── web/
    │   ├── main.tf
    ├── database/
    │   ├── main.tf
```

To be able to use these modules you need to include them in `my-terraform-project/main.tf` specifying their paths in `source`. Otherwise Terraform will ignore them.

```
module "web" {
  source = "./modules/web"
}

module "database" {
  source = "./modules/database"
}
```

Note that each module must declare its own provider requirements in case you do not want to use default provider configurations (see [child model inheritance](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/modules/develop/providers#implicit-provider-inheritance)).